# Manager trying to undermine my performance after I helped bring in more than $1 million for the company

Tags: management, manager, billing, healthcare-industry

I started at this job 5 months ago and was hired permanently full time about a month and a half later. It's a medical billing department apart of a non-profit healthcare organization that manages multiple health centers.

Their A/R (accounts receivables) was at 62 days when I started. I was told by the director that it was stuck in the 60s for more than two years. He gave me some excuse about them having a problem collecting from a certain provider class (insurance) and blamed them among other things, for not paying on time. Most of these claims were denied and are between 1-2 years old, totalling about two million dollars. According to the director, they made a deal with them that would allow them to resubmit them for payment on the condition that it would be resubmitted quickly and accurately. I was hired as a temp to help resubmit more than two thousand claims to this insurance company. I basically had to do someone elses work (their own that financial class)

Long story short, the A/R is currently at 49 days as of today. Around the time they decided to officially hire me full time, the A/R was at 55 days and they had a small celebration which included catered Chinese food.

During this whole time I could sense some sort of resentment from my supervisor (not director), almost as if I've done my job too well. She then started to micromanage my time once they A/R fell below 50.

I admit, I came in late some days but nothing more than five minutes. My situation is complex; I broke my leg earlier this year in January in a bike accident and after four months I needed to get back to work (funds save ran low and this job is close to my home), so I took whatever I could get as fast as possible.

The supervisor wrote me up a few weeks ago because of lateness and included some lies about my performance. Thing is, when the A/R started to drop, about a month after I started, they introduced a 7 minute grace period policy meaning that you can clock in seven minutes before or after and not get dinged. I walk everyday to work and they know I occasionally have pain bouts and have to slow down my pace, which resulted in me coming in a few minutes late. I also kept the grace period in mind each day.

So she writes me up and includes other lies about my performance. Mind you, the A/r was stuck at over 60 days for more than two years before I started, and is now at 49 days only after a couple of months. I've seen other managers in different departments get promoted, more employee engagement activities, more potlucks and more events created by HR, because the money was flowing in FAST. Everyone in the office even got new monitors except for me (yes, office politics) and some even got more on their annual raise (I only got 20 cents and didn't get a meeting about it; had to go to payroll to find out).

The lies she included about my performance where based on other employees work assigned to me. She claimed that I couldn't grasp to work fast enough, even though some of those employees purposely sabotaged me when training me. Giving me false information or leaving out important details or not answering any of my questions that seem to detailed for them. Basically its bullshit, and I believe shes trying to start a paper trail to get me out. My belief is that because I submitted all of those claims very fast and even finishing other assignments quickly, she felt insulted and decided to undermine all the hard work I put in.

Should I just leave and let them deal with increasing A/R themselves?

Comment: And you're sure that the backlog is going down because of your specific work, and not just because they have an additional body working on it?

Comment: They already went through three temps and two potential full times within months before I joined. One full timer quit the first day. I got this info from other employees during breaks, looking out for me on what to expect from management.

Comment: Generally, if you ask what to do, or are just ranting, the question will be closed.  However, if you change the question and ask for ways to turn this around and be successful in this job, in spite of a manager that could be working against you, someone might come up with some decent ideas.

Comment: I took this job for because my savings was running low. I have more skills but wanted something with structure and a pay check to survive. I freelance on my off time and on the weekends and even started doing doordash on my bike to help strengthen my bad leg.

Comment: A main part of a manager's job is motivate their people to do work. A manager could be amazing at motivating people or just have incredibly self-motivated employees. From your description, it sounds like the latter. Some thing that would help your case. How many other people are in your function? Are you performing better than they are?

Comment: You did say she could by working against me which makes me think I should quit.I honestly didn't intend for this to be a rant. It's just too many details to include that may get me the answer I know too be morally correct. Less details in my mind would give me more accurate advice regardless of how it 'sounds'.

Comment: @jcmack About 10 others and if you look at the a/r reports, they are all doing the bare minimum for YEARS. Only two people have been their for 1-2 years. The rest more than 10 and MOST are retirement age.

Comment: @Space_Wiz Okay now you're starting to make a case for yourself. You can continue to work against your manager, which will make your life pretty miserable for the time being. Or make a case why you were the one that really made an impact on A/R. You're really new as a full-timer too. I definitely recommend playing nice with your manager right now. Take some time and talk about the 7 minute grace period given to all employees.

Comment: @jcmack I did and even showed her notes from one our staff meetings that was posted on the company intranet. She claimed she misspoke, and that the policy only applies to 7 minutes BEFORE.

Comment: Yes, you need to leave.

Comment: @Space_Wiz If _she_ "misspoke", then it is _not your fault_ and she has no ground for a write-up. I don't want to recommend it to you, but if I were in your shoes, I'd very carefully include some higher-up into the suspicion I was being targeted. No accusations, I'd just lay out the facts and that those make me feel uncomfortable. Maybe I'd phrase it as a request for advice on what to do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Should I just leave and let them deal with increasing A/R themselves?

Clearly you aren't happy here and have no confidence in your boss, your colleagues, or the company. The word you are using ("undermine", "sabotage", "lies", "office politics", "only got 20 cents", etc) indicate that you don't want to be at your current job

Of course this is something you must decide for yourself. But I believe you should find a new job, give the appropriate notice and leave.

Answer (score 10):

If the manager sees you as a threat because you are actually making things happen when she and previous workers under her have not, then you may or may not be able to salvage this job.  If it's a decent job other than this manager, it's probably worth a try to salvage it.

You need to make sure that she has NOTHING more that she can use against you.  Don't be even 30 seconds late (and leave earlier if need be).  Always be pleasant to her, and especially be pleasant to others around you.  Make sure people like you, if you have an opportunity to say hi to people above her, make sure they see you as a pleasant and hard worker.

That way, when she makes an accusation against you, you'll have the time clock on your side, and other people will be confused, because they see your great work, they see your great attitude.  If she makes up things, it will be obvious it's from her, not you.  You want to be so perfect that anything against you just sounds crazy.

If done right and if management above her is halfway competent, she will be demoted or replaced. (Unfortunately, my experience with bad management means a bad manager above that allows it, and often it's seagulls all the way up.)

Comment: In this case its the director that placed her in position less  than two years ago. I got this from other employee who willfully told me out of the blue. So I think you experience with this may match up with mine which is why I don't care to leave. I actually want the A/R to jump back up

Comment: Seems you already made up your mind, and if you ask me, correctly so. I do hope, for your revenge sake, that the AR _do_ climb back up... a manager who's intimidated and humiliated by her own employee and a higher-up manager not noticing this and letting her have a free rule?! Only sad thing is there are way too many such companies. Leave and hopefully, you'll land on one company which is *not* like those. Good luck.

Comment: @O.F. By "specific range" I meant the actual percentage of the raise. They gave the raise early to all employees in all departments including the nursing/ support staff.

Answer (score 3):

#### You sound very unhappy there, conditions are unlikely to change, and leaving is the most direct solution.

I've worked in a hospital and closely with hospital financial offices, and what you describe is not unusual. Especially at a large hospital, individual departments can be run like fiefs with people in charge making decisions based on personal relationships more than anything else with little accountability (outside of a colossal screw-up).

There are a few things I'll mention about hospitals that are relevant to the situation. I suspect you know them already, but future visitors to the site might not have the relevant hospital experience to know the context:

- Having a "bad" stat, like a high A/R, isn't usually something that
  hospitals *want*. But it *is* usually something they can usually
  *handle*. I'm sure they were delighted to see the A/R below 60, but they operated for years with it above 60. This isn't a good leverage
  point for you.
- Hospitals see *enormous* flows of money. A million dollars sounds
  like, and is, a lot, but it's almost certainly far less significant
  to the hospital. As above, this is not a very good leverage point for
  you.
- Hospitals can describe outstanding bills in terms of *charges*, *expected payments*, and *contracted reimbursement* rates, and are often unclear in which term they're using for internal discussions. If they were describing one
  million dollars in *charges*, then the money the hospital actually
  received is almost certainly quite a bit less than that. Clearing
  $1,000,000 from the ledger is not the same as bringing $1,000,000 in
  cash into the hospital.
- The tardiness is a problem. Many roles in hospitals require constant
  staffing, and so timeclock rules can be *very* strict, even in roles
  where shift timing is not so critical. (This described my hospital
  role as well, and I too had some tardiness issues for similar
  reasons). If they care about clocking in on time, then no excuse or
  explanation for repeated tardiness will be accepted. They will always
  say you should have left for work earlier.
- I can appreciate that the $0.20 raise was disappointing, but you've
  been at this job for *less than six months*; it would not have
  surprised me to find out that you were not eligible for a raise at
  all due to that. Also, many hospital departments are pretty
  constrained in what budget they have for raises, and what conditions
  they can offer raises under. It's possible that your manager had no
  discretion in setting your raise (especially if the workforce at your
  hospital is unionized).

None of that is meant to denigrate your work, at all. Hospitals can be intense, high-stress work environments dealing with a never-ending avalanche of complicated work. But it is important to remember that people at the hospital, especially in management, will probably have a very different perspective on how things unfolded than you do, and they are less likely to be moved by your story.

As written, the question pretty clearly transmits an attitude that you, personally and by yourself, were responsible for $1,000,000 in cash rolling into the hospital. And that that excellent performance entitles you to some extra leeway and consideration. And even though that performance resulted in more money and better working conditions for *everyone*, there are still quite a few people out to actively sabotage you.

All of those things can be true, but it's a less than compelling case to simply hear without a great deal of specific evidence backing each item. And even if you had such evidence, it's far from guaranteed that you can force the department to change how it operates.

**It sounds like you're unhappy with the work environment and the pay you receive, and it also sounds like neither of those is likely to change in ways you want. If that's so, then of course you should leave.** Why would you want to remain? But don't expect the hospital to collapse behind you. The high A/R is their *normal state*.

Comment: Itrs not a hospital but a network of community health centers that provide care for all (even if they don't have insurance).

Comment: Also, the director hinted that they may have to outsource. This was on my second day as if it was a was to con to me to work hard. The crazy part is that he was probably telling the truth.